# Adding menustripitems on top of existing ones

Tags: vb.net, contextmenustrip

In my simple WinForm application I have a ContextMenuStrip. This is palced during design time and few items have been added in designer mode. For example following items are added during design time,

```
--------
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
--------
Close
Exit
```

Now I am getting the Groups from database. Each Group can have multiple users. So first I create the Groups using this code,

```
For Each drGroup In dtGroups.Rows
   Dim groupMenu As New ToolStripMenuItem() With {.Text = drGroup ("GroupName"),
                                                       .Name = RemoveWhitespace(drGroup ("GroupName"))
                                                      }
   myCMS.Items.Add(groupMenu)                
Next
```

I am not mentioning the code for adding sub items for groups as it is beyond the context of this question. Now my context menu strip is like this,

```
--------
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
--------
Close
Exit
Group 1
Group 2
Group 3
Group 4
Group 5
```

But I want the output like this,

```
Group 1
Group 2
Group 3
Group 4
Group 5
--------
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
--------
Close
Exit
```

I have no idea how I can achieve this. One way could be to remove the existing items and re-add them after all dynamic items are created but is there any other solution.

Comment: `myCMS.Items.Insert(0, groupMenu)`

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for your response. I will not try your suggestion in my code. But just a quick question. Do you think that inserting an Item at Index 0 will automatically change the Index of existing item at Index 0?

Comment: If you insert an item at index 0 that _will indeed_ change the old index 0 item's index to 1. That is what indexes represent - where in the list you have the items. You cannot have two index 0 items.

Comment: @LarsTech Don't be confused. I meant "I will try your suggestion" but have written "not" by mistake and didn't noticed it. I have already tested it and was going to ask you to write this comments of your as an answer so I could mark it as accepted answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding items, you can simply insert them into the beginning of the list:

```
myCMS.Items.Insert(0, groupMenu)
```

This will change the "index" values of the existing items in the current list.